# Design GET API having sorting functionality in .NET Core

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design, webapi

Here's my problem statement in short.

I'm going to get 5 properties and its sort order i.e. asc or desc and on basis of that i need to do sorting on backend and need to deliver data back to UI.

For this requirement i'm thinking of creating a model class with 5 properties. That property would look like below example.

```
               property_Name, sort_order
 (Where property_Name = Name & sort_order = asc or Ascending)

                   example : "Name,asc"
```

I'm thinking of to keep it as a string and I'll split it at backend once i receive it. and will perform sort operation thereafter.

I'm unable to think further on how to make it more elegant & clean code.

Any pointers or help is welcomed.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. here's one: `[HttpGet, Route("sortProps")] public IActionResult SortProperties([FromQuery] IEnumerable<string> prop, [FromQuery] bool sortAsc){ /* do work */ }` then call it is `https://example.com/api/sortProps/?prop=first&prop=second&prop=third&prop=fourth&prop=fifth&sortAsc=true`.

Comment: We took similar path last time. The only downside here is, if, by any chance in future if query parameters increase then there's a problem as different browsers have query string limit.

Comment: Then you'll want to move away from `HttpGet` to `HttpPost` and send the data in the body.

Comment: currently i have formed an object to house all the properties. Will sending an object in GET API be against REST principles ?  I'm too not much aware of that side.

Comment: You can't put data in the body of an `HttpGet`. You have to use the url path, query or header. You already said the url is out, and headers don't get you much more room, so your only option is to change it to an `HttpPost` and use the Body.

Comment: @Andy makes sense though. Will re-think on my approach. Thanks man for the pointer.